# Free alternative to step-by-step-solution feature of Wolfram|Alpha Pro?

Tags: gratis, math

Are there any **free** online and/or offline alternatives to the step-by-step-solution feature of Wolfram|Alpha Pro?

This feature is able to display step-by-step-solutions of a wide variety of algebra problems, as shown in the example screenshot below.

[image: Wolfram|Alpha Pro step-by-step-solutions]

https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another great alternative is: https://www.symbolab.com/

It has also got a premium area, but its step-by-step solutions are free.

Example Screenshot:
[image: Symbolab Step-by-Step]

Comment: Aditya at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48818/free-alternative-to-step-by-step-solution-feature-of-wolfram-alpha-pro says it is not free anymore. @itaton can you confirm?

Comment: Seems to be not free any more,  and more expensive than Wolfram mobile

Comment: Still works for me on the website I linked. I don't know about (and haven't tested) any mobile app, which is what the question Nicolas Raoul referenced is asking.

Comment: After using symbolab for a while, very disappointed. It's not free (requires payment for many advanced features, pretty much like WolframAlpha), it's just horribly buggy, and the functionality is very limited. You can't even copy and paste the formula in the graphing area, for example.

Comment: This is not true (at least as of now). I see a padlock "Show steps" button, and it says: "Subscribe to get much more: Full access to solution steps", "From $1.99".

Answer (score 16):

I know this isn't free, but the Wolfram Alpha mobile phone app has a one-time cost of $2.99 (at least on Android) and offers step-by-step solutions without needing a Pro account.

[image: Screenshot showing the WolframAlpha Pro app with steps at solving a differential equation]

Comment: works the same for ios too, as at this time

Comment: Still seems to work as of November 2020.

Answer (score 7):

One good alternative is:
http://gamma.sympy.org/

It doesn't show steps for factoring but it does show steps for more complicated things in Calculus like derivatives and integrals.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't show steps for many complicated limits, integrals, etc. for which WolframAlpha does have steps available.

Answer (score 3):

Another free option is [photomath](https://photomath.net/en/). Not as advanced as WolframAlpha, but may be suitable. It is available for Android.

Answer (score 2):

Another free option is [www.emathhelp.net](http://www.emathhelp.net)

Comment: Does this have step-by-step? Cause I don't see anything that looks like it.

Comment: @MaxD this is not a one page website. The calculators are on different pages. Derivative calculator - https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/derivative-calculator/ Use search in the upper-right corner. Or google "your query emathhelp", e.g. "factoring calculator emathhelp".

Answer (score 1):

Open Omnia is an alternative to Wolfram Alpha Pro and Symbolab. Disclaimer: I am the developer.

You can find the web application here: https://openomnia.com and the android app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.openomnia.openomnia

Feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Microsoft Edge come with something called [Math Solver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/05/21/preview-microsoft-math-solver-microsoft-edge/):

[image: Math Solver screenshot]

It provides the option to either type in the math problem or select it on the screen.

Math Solver is also accessible if you try searching for a math problem on Bing:

[image: Math Solver on Bing]

Also through a direct URL: https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en

I tried it and was quite impressed:

[image: Math Solver example]

Comment: MS Mah Solver does not support pasting equations but one can replace the last part of the URL after 'solve-problem/' instead

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Mathematics) is a great alternative to Mathematica.

Note that I am a user of both Wolfram Mathematica and Microsoft Mathematics 4.0 .

Though the User Interface is a bit outdated, it has a lot of Mathematica-grade features.

Answer (score -1):

I've just found [fxSolver](https://www.fxsolver.com/)... It doesn't seem to show all the workings, but it does provide help and background on the inputs, and allows plotting.

[image: fxSolver vs Bernoulli]

Comment: I can't find any step-by-step feature on this site. Note that this question doesn't ask for a general alternative to Wolfram, but specifically for the step-by-step solution feature.