# Free mobile alternative to step-by-step-solution feature of Wolfram Alpha Pro?

Tags: gratis, math, educational

Are there any free online and/or offline alternatives to the step-by-step-solution feature of Wolfram Alpha Pro that **can be used on Mobile phone**?

This feature is able to display step-by-step-solutions of a wide variety of algebra problems.

Earlier there was SymboLab. Now their mobile version has gone paid.

Answer (score 6):

[SymPy Gamma](http://gamma.sympy.org/) is a free web application based on [SymPy](http://sympy.org/). It returns step-by-step solutions for some types of high school / college math problems, for example:

- [Find the derivative of `x*sin(x)**2`](http://gamma.sympy.org/input/?i=diff%28x*sin%28x%29**2%2C+x%29)
- [Integrate `x*sin(3*x)`](http://gamma.sympy.org/input/?i=integrate%28x*sin%283*x%29%2C+x%29)
- [Integrate `x**2/(x**2+1)`](http://gamma.sympy.org/input/?i=integrate%28x**2%2F%28x**2%2B1%29%2C+x%29)

It's rougher around the edges and the syntax is a bit more rigid than WolframAlpha's. One can use `^` instead of `**` for powers (there is some preprocessing for that) but otherwise, the closer you are to standard SymPy syntax, the better. For example, one can type `integrate x*sin(3*x)` instead of `integrate(x*sin(3*x), x)` and it's understood correctly. But when I tried `integrate x**2/(x**2+1)`, SymPy Gamma misunderstood it as "the integral of `x**2`, divided by `(x**2+1)`".

It does not seem to have any step-by-step for *algebra* problems like "solve this quadratic equation", however.

(Disclosure: I am a SymPy developer, though I had no part in SymPy Gamma specifically.)

Comment: How do I write roots in Sympy?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2-16} - (x-4) - \sqrt{x^2-5x+4}$

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh you could use the fact that $\sqrt{x} = x^{0.5}$, so you could use `x**0.5`

Answer (score 1):

### Integral Calculator & Derivative Calculator websites

- https://www.integral-calculator.com/
- https://www.derivative-calculator.net/

Features:

- Both are free-to-use websites, which are also responsive on mobile phone screens.
- Both show steps
- The backend employs the CAS [Maxima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_(software)) (GPL software).

Limitations:

- Unfortunately, you can only integrate and differentiate with respect to a single variable.

Comment: The question has been modified because it was a duplicate. Now this question is about mobile. If your answer is not for mobile, please move it to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16865/free-alternative-to-step-by-step-solution-feature-of-wolframalpha-pro thanks and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

Open Omnia is an alternative to Wolfram Alpha Pro and Symbolab. Disclaimer: I am the developer.

You can find the web application here: https://openomnia.com and the android app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.openomnia.openomnia

Feel free to try it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please read the [rules](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) we have when it comes to promoting your own product.

Comment: Hi Lloyd!  Can you please describe your products and how they meet the OP's requirements?  Also, screenshots would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Wolfram Alpha is too expensive and commercial. Being a student, I use [Free integral calculator](https://www.calculatored.com/math/calculus/integral-calculator). Both desktop and mobile versions are available for this calculator, and it is ad-free.

Comment: Welcome James! We've noticed that you have recommended this website many times in a short period of time.  Please fully disclose your affiliation in your answer.  Please also explain how it fully meets the question's requirements; does it actually show step-by-step solutions?